# X86 clear interrupt flag instruction `cli` not working in user space?

Tags: linux, performance, x86, interrupt

I try to stop interrupts from user space for a specific isolated core,

so I set CPU affinity:

```
cpu_set_t set;
CPU_ZERO(&set);
CPU_SET(2, &set);
assert(sched_setaffinity(getpid(),sizeof(set),&set)==0);
```

and use`iopl(3)` to execute privileged instruction `cli/sti` in user space:

```
iopl(3);
__asm__("cli;");
// busy looping for a while
__asm__("sti;");
```

and there are two phenomenons I can't explain:

1 `cli` can't actually stop interrupts (at least not all interrupts), and interrupt, such as LOC (Local Timer Interrupt) comes out every now and then;

I notice lasted kernel patches prevent `cli` in user space ([reference](https://lwn.net/Articles/804094/)) , but this result can be reproduced in kernel 4.19.0.

2 AFAIK, `cli` only clear interrupt flag of CPU on which the program is running, but in practice, my whole system is stuck,  not responding to my mouse or keyboard.

Comment: modifying iopl is a privileged instruction.

Comment: Yes, as well as the instruction `cli`. the program should run with sudo/root.

Answer (score 2):

(2): Many parts of the Linux kernel depend on communicating with other cores, including RCU depending on `for each core: run_on(core)` and stuff like that.  (https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/).  Any kernel code doing that will get stuck when this core doesn't respond to the IPI that other cores send to ask the kernel on this core to switch to a certain task, or perhaps to do TLB shootdowns.

I don't know what exact thing would tend to lead to getting stuck, but I don't find it surprising at all that other parts of the kernel are waiting for something that depends on hearing back from the kernel on this core, and that blocks progress of something involved in getting keyboard/mouse events to an X server and to user-space.  (Or even to a text console?  That might have more hope, fewer layers of software.)

Or it's always possible that some keyboard or mouse interrupts get distributed to this core, and ignored.

---

As for (1): do you leave the NMI watchdog enabled, or other source of NMIs?  That could get the kernel running temporarily in a state where (other?) interrupts are enabled.

I use `kernel/nmi_watchdog = 0` in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf` to free up an extra perf counter, but the default is enabled.

(`cli` doesn't stop Non-Maskable Interrupts, as you might guess from the name.)

Other than that guess, I don't know why you'd still be occasional LOCal timer interrupts; maybe someone more familiar with modern x86 interrupts would know.

Comment: Thanks, you remind me that RCU remote IPI uses a spinlock busy waiting for the  remote function call to be finished, and this may stuck cpu0.

Comment: `nmi_watchdog` has already been closed by the kernel parameter `nmi_watchdog=0`.

Answer (score -1):

1. cli only mask maskable interrupts. local timer interrupts are not maskable (NMI). see this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/microprocessor/microprocessor_8086_interrupts.htm
2. You can try linux kernel with tickless operation (CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y) to reduce the number of local timer interrupts to 1 per second. see this https://docs.kernel.org/timers/no_hz.html